# Вывод определенных ресурсов в Opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

У меня проблема с синтаксисом, не могу никак найти информации по нему для opencart 3 версии.
Не получается вывести какой то отдельный ресурс или подкатегорию.
Пытался выводить таким способом:

Для статей:

```
<li><a href="{{ information.href[7] }}">{{ information.title[7] }}</a></li>
```

Для дочерних ресурсов в меню:

```
<li><a href="{{ child.href[3] }}">{{ child.name[3] }}</a></li>
```

Где у меня ошибка понять не могу, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Пробуйте что-то типа

```
{% if informations %}

{% for information in informations %}

{% if information.id == '7' %}
<li><a href="{{ information.href }}">{{ information.title }}</a></li>
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```